pod 'Firebase/Core', '11.5.0' is not working
Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong.

Xcode - Version 15.3
iOS - Sonoma Version 14.5 , apple M3Max
cocoapods - Version 1.15.2

below is the pod file.
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'connectdots' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for connectdots
  pod ‘Firebase/Core’, '11.5.0'
  pod ‘Firebase/AdMob’, '11.5.0'
  
end

below is the error I got when I run pod install --repo update
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Core":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Core (= 11.5.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/Core (= 11.5.0)`.

You have either:
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Firebase/Core and Firebase/AdMob need to be updated to latest version
I tried some other solutions found on the internet, but nothing is solving my problem.

Do
  pod 'FirebaseAnalytics', '10.27.0'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '11.5.0'

The latest version of Firebase is 10.27.0
AdMob is no longer a subspec of Firebase.
